# Downloaded plist (in NSString) convert to NSArray

Tags: parsing, nsarray, plist

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. I have a simple plist on my server.

I am using the ASIHTTPRequest framework, so I can get both the data object and a string.

Outputting: `[[NSString alloc] initWithData:[request responseData] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]` works just fine and the output it the plist.

However, I cannot get this parsed into an NSArray. I have tried with: `[[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSString alloc] initWithData:[request responseData] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]` but without any luck.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you create plist file that contain elements array then`initWithContentsOfFile:` works fine. The argument to '-[NSArray initWithContentsOfFile:]' should be a file path and file should be stored locally. That means the app should have read access to the stored file.

If your server is giving you plist file content , you can store it locally and use `initWithContentsOfFile:` method create array from file content.

Regards

Devara Gudda